# How to remove border from FriendFeed widget?

Tags: css, widget, border, feed, friendfeed

FriendFeed offers a [widget](http://friendfeed.com/embed/widget) with some [CSS customization possible](http://friendfeed.com/embed/css).  But it seems you can't remove the border (the blue big one around all cotent)?  The widget has a URL like

```
http://friendfeed.com/embed/widget/FOOBAR?v=2&amp;num=30&amp;hide_logo=1&amp;hide_comments_likes=0&amp;hide_subscribe=1
```

where `FOOBAR` is a user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS try for v3:

```
#friendfeed.widget { border: 0 !important;}​
```

or this for v2:

```
.friendfeed.widget { border: 0 !important;}​
```

If you also want to remove the logo at the top, add:

```
#friendfeed .logo img { display: none; }
```

Comment: The first didn't remove the border. Any other idea?

Comment: It seemed to work for me on Chrome and Firefox. Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9bdH/1/)

Comment: That's because you are using `v=3` while I'm using `v=2`?

Comment: Could you explain a little why `#` for v3 and `.` for v2?

Comment: In v3, friendfeed uses <div id= "friendfeed" class="widget"> and in v2 friendfeed uses <div class="friendfeed widget">. In css, you use the '.' notation to correspond with a class, and the '#' notation to correspond with an id

Comment: Thanks for the input. "friendfeed widget" with the space means using a class in a class? Where did you see the `<div ...>` code?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can right click on the JSFiddle instance (or any webpage) and click 'Inspect Element' which will show you the html/css code. If you are using Firefox, you can use the Firebug plugin. Not sure about IE